# Can I create a break inside a single unordered list?

Tags: html, css

The layout I want to achieve is the following, one large image with a gallery of four thumbnails below it:

[image]

I'm using a Javascript gallery to actually display a full screen gallery, activated when clicking on this element.

The problem is that the gallery script expects the images as direct children in an unordered list, all of them including the one that is the big image in my layout:

```
<ul>
  <li data-src="img1.jpg">
      <img src="thumb1.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li data-src="img2.jpg">
      <img src="thumb2.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

The first `<li>` is the big image, all the others are small thumbnails.

Is there a way to achive my desired layout while still having all the images in the unordered list? If I could break up the list this would be easy, but that wouldn't be recognized by the gallery script anymore.

Is it possible to achive this layout without changing the underlying structure of the list?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `float: left` and `display: block` on `li`, and `float: none` on `li:first-child`:

```css
ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li
{
    margin: 2px 5px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
li:first-child
{
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/430/430/" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" />
  </li>
  <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Simple and clean, no JS involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt based on flexbox. The skewed images are a side effect of taking random cat images from the web, and constraining them to a certain width and height ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/av29prbo/3/)).

The CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    /** add box-sizing: border-box; if you include padding or borders **/
}

li:first-child {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

li:not(:first-child) {
    /** add box-sizing: border-box; if you include padding or borders **/
    width: 25%; /** use calc if you include margins **/
    height: 100px; /** whatever height you want **/
}

li > img { /** demo only - because of image sizes **/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li data-src="whatever">
      <img src="http://www.gordonrigg.com/the-hub/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/little_cute_cat_1920x1080.jpg" />
  </li>

  <li data-src="whatever">
      <img src="http://rufflifechicago.com/wp-content/uploads/cat-treats.jpg" />
  </li>

  <li data-src="whatever">
      <img src="http://www.vetprofessionals.com/catprofessional/images/home-cat.jpg" />
  </li>

  <li data-src="whatever">
      <img src="http://animalia-life.com/data_images/cat/cat8.jpg" />
  </li>

  <li data-src="whatever">
      <img src="http://www.catprotection.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/5507692-cat-m.jpg" />
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for some simple CSS, there are multiple ways to approach this, the easiest is likely:

```
<style type="text/css">
  ul.thumbs li{
    float:right;
  }
</style>
<ul class="thumbs">
  <li data-src="img1.jpg">
      <img src="thumb1.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li data-src="img2.jpg">
      <img src="thumb2.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

you could also set the `ul` to `display:table-row` and the `li`s to `display:table-cell` which would allow them to evenly spread and fill the space allowed in the `ul`

Based on your edit you will need something a little more complicated, without knowing which plugin you are using, or how it works, you can try this approach (uses a little jQuery):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').click(function(){
          $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
      });
    });
```

```css
ul{
    padding-top:405px;
    position:relative;
}
li{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}
li.selected{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="selected">test 1</li>
    <li>test 2</li>
    <li>test 3</li>
    <li>test 4</li>
    <li>test 5</li>
</ul>
```